# video.js html5 video freezes in google chrome

Tags: video.js

I have a problem in Google Chrome where I'm trying to play a video and the video freezes after about 5 seconds and then appears to run to the end and the entire video stops. I'm using Video.js

Here is the video playback page where the problem exists: http://bililly.aliendevelopment.com/video-only.php

Any help or direction in troubleshooting this is much appreciated.

Comment: Update: this problem occurs in all browsers on Windows PC's but only in Chrome and Safari on OS X Lion computers. Firefox appears to be fine on OS X Lion.

Comment: Update: The problem has been solved....thank you to those who considered answering....the problem was a corrupted video file.